# wso2 how to invoke secure service with crt and keyfile

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have this curl example:

`curl -X POST --url https://xxxxxxx/xx/xx -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username": " [user] " ,"password": " [password] " }' --cert ./[crtarhive].crt:[password] --key ./[keyfile]`

and i wanted to develop this service in wso2 enterprise integrator but i dont have any clue how to work with the crt, password and key file.
I tried to unify in a pfx file the cert and key file using:
`openssl pkcs12 -export -in ./[crtarchive].crt -inkey ./[keyfile].key -passin pass:[password -out [pfxarchive].pfx`

then extract the private key and remove the phassprase. The result of this is a pem file that if i use in a curl the service respond correctly without keyfile and password.
So i import the pem file into the client-trustore and i make a simple proxy service but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply invoke an HTTPS service in the EI server with curl, you can add the -k flag to the request.

```
curl -X POST --url https://xxxxxxx/xx/xx -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username": " [user] " ,"password": " [password] " }' -k
```

Invoking an HTTPS service in the EI and securing a service in EI (for example basic OAuth) are two different scenarios. If you want to secure service you can refer to the documentation [1], [2].

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Applying+Security+to+an+API
[2]-https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/advanced-development/applying-security-to-a-proxy-service/

Comment: What i need is create a proxy service in wso2 ei to invoke that https service. The curl is the example to how invoke it.

Comment: Can you clarify more on the request to be made to the backend? Does this has to have a  JSON payload with the username and password parameters

Comment: The request is a POST message with a json payload with username and password (this is one of many services that i will use). The problem that i have its with how to make the connection to the provider using the certificate and the key that i mention.